# left join with at least one row with condition from right mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I have 2 tables, restaurants and orders, orders table have `restaurant_id`, `status` and `date` fields, each day is a separate line in orders table.

I need to filter the restaurants and show only the restaurants that have at least one reservation for some date range, but I have to show it on a calendar, it should look like a list of restaurants with information.

Smth like this

[image]

So, it means that if `at least one day with reserved status` condition is satisfied in that date range, all the orders for that date range for that restaurant should be fetched as well.

I can not make a usual inner join,

```
SELECT r.`id`, r.`name`, o.`date`, o.`status`
FROM restaurants r
INNER JOIN orders o ON r.id = o.restaurant_id AND o.date BETWEEN '2013-08-10' AND '2013-08-31'
AND status = 'reserved'
```

because, in this case, for example, I will not have the order information for August 31, for restaurant2, because though it is in date rage from 10 - 31, but its status is 'closed'.
So, I am thinking to make a left join like this

```
SELECT r.`id`, r.`name`, o.`date`, o.`status`,  o.`id` order_id
FROM restaurants r
LEFT JOIN orders o ON r.id = o.restaurant_id AND
o.date BETWEEN '2013-08-10' AND '2013-08-31' 
WHERE o.`id` IS NOT NULL
```

But I need to also add one condition to ensure that there is at least one row with order's status = 'reserved',  I tried to add where clause like `COUNT(o.status = 1) > 0` but it gives an error.

THanks

Comment: Use a subquery to get the restauants with at least one record where the status is reserved.  Then you can use an inner join.

Comment: @DanBracuk Could you expand a little about it? Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I think the best way to achieve this (assuming things like 'N/A' and 'reserved' are stored in the orders table is to join to all orders in the first instance, and then use a second join to limit it to only restaurants that have a reservation within that period:

```
SELECT  r.`id`, r.`name`, o.`date`, o.`status`,  o.`id` order_id
FROM    restaurants r
        INNER JOIN orders o 
            ON r.id = o.restaurant_id
            AND o.date BETWEEN '2013-08-10' AND '2013-08-31' 
        INNER JOIN
        (   SELECT  DISTINCT o2.Restaurant_ID
            FROM    orders o2
            WHERE   o2.date BETWEEN '2013-08-10' AND '2013-08-31' 
            AND     o2.Status = 'Reserved'
        ) o2
            ON r.id = o2.restaurant_id;
```

**[Example on SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/81df8/4)**

Comment: u have no idea how much I am thankful to u :). Thanks a lot. And lemme ask one thing - will this be very expensive if I have hundreds of thousands of restaurants? And what indices will I need to optimize it ?

Comment: Yes, this is probably the most scalable solution. I don't know what other queries you might use on the tables, but for this I would either have 3 indexes on `orders` on `restaurant_id`, `status` and `date`, or depending on your distribution it may better to only have 2 indexes, with one of them being on two of the columns, hard to say exactly without knowing the distribution of the data. e.g. If each `order` is unique per restaurant per day, then I would add a unique index on these two columns, with a single nonclustered index on status.

Comment: Thanks you really very much for your help. I wanted to ask one more thing. I tried to use the same query but with left join (anti-join) in order to get the free restaruants, but I could not figure it out, if you could help me with it, that would be great - I posted a new question for that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18362311/left-join-with-empty-rows-from-right-table-mysql. Thanks